# Jupyter Notebook (iPython) gives fatal error when starting

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jinja2, seaborn, ipython

I updated seaborn from 0.9.0 to 0.11.2 and when I did, it broke my jupyter notebook installation. I have uninstalled and reinstalled jinja2 using pip, conda, and brew, have also removed all package dependencies for seaborn and reinstalled seaborn and have done the same for the jupyter package, but errors persist. I also repeated these steps after upgrading pip3 to the latest version. I am on Mac 10.13.6 in a python3.6 virtual env. This is the error I am receiving currently:

jupyter notebook

```
[I 11:13:42.913 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: / <br>
[I 11:13:42.913 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.7 is running at:<br> 
[I 11:13:42.913 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=34df74d20991ab66bb0b7c7cbae590fb17146e8f1e8ea0b2<br>
[I 11:13:42.913 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=34df74d20991ab66bb0b7c7cbae590fb17146e8f1e8ea0b2<br>
[I 11:13:42.913 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).<br>
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "/python/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in <module><br>
    sys.exit(main())<br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 264, in launch_instance<br>
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)<br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance<br>
    app.start()<br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2338, in start <br>
    self.write_browser_open_file() <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2242, in write_browser_open_file <br>
    self._write_browser_open_file(open_url, f)<br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2250, in _write_browser_open_file <br>
    template = jinja2_env.get_template('browser-open.html') <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 997, in get_template <br>
    return self._load_template(name, globals) <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 958, in _load_template <br>
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals)) <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 137, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename) <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 749, in compile <br>
    source = self._parse(source, name, filename) <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 606, in _parse <br>
    return Parser(self, source, name, filename).parse() <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 1038, in parse <br>
    result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1) <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 1012, in subparse <br>
    add_data(self.parse_tuple(with_condexpr=True)) <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 725, in parse_tuple <br>
    args.append(parse()) <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 523, in parse_expression <br>
    return self.parse_condexpr() <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 528, in parse_condexpr <br>
    expr1 = self.parse_or() <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 543, in parse_or <br>
    left = self.parse_and() <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 552, in parse_and <br>
    left = self.parse_not() <br>
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 560, in parse_not <br>
    if self.stream.current.test("name:not"): <br>
AttributeError: 'Token' object has no attribute 'test'
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgqN0.png)

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I found this: [AttributeError: 'Token' object has no attribute 'test' while starting notebook](https://giters.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6084), [SO: Flask : 'Token' object has no attribute 'test' | render_template error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67659135/7758804), and [SO: AttributeError: 'Token' object has no attribute 'test' when running jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68311419/7758804)

Comment: Seems to be a `jinja2` issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it looks like I need to update python as well

Comment: I wouldn't mess with system python. You might want to install the Anaconda distribution for python, which has a Linux and mac version. https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads